How can I solve the no module_found issue in Django?
After creating the venv I have installed the django to the venv. Also I have added the installed apps, but its showing no module named module_name.settings error. Can anyone help ?

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatbot.settings'

I was trying to create a chatbot and actually it were working in the beginning, because of an issue in git I just changed the folder. Since that happens the same error is showing. And also I have tried to create the project from the beginning and the same error is happening.
